# Cut files from 1 files and grep -v from another files

Tags: bash

```
File1
Ada
Billy
Charles
Delta
Eight
```

```
File2
Ada,User,xxx
Beba,User,xxx
Charles,Admin,xxx
```

I am exuting the following

```
Acc=`cut -d',' -f1 $PATH/File2
for account in `cat $File1 |grep -v Acc`
do
cat......
sed....
```

How to correct this?>

Expect output

Check file2 account existing on file1

```
Ada
Charles
```

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk -F, 'FNR == NR {seen[$1]; next} $1 in seen' file2 file1

Ada
Charles
```

If this is not the output you're looking for then edit your question and add your expected output.

Comment: @Kenny: I have updated answer to match your expected output from question. Let me know if it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Your grep command searches for files which do not contain the string *Acc*. You need the Flag `-f`, which causes grep to accept a list of pattern from a file, something like this:

```
tmpf=/tmp/$$
cut -d',' -f1 File2 >$tmpf
for account in $(grep -f "$tmpf" File1)
do
  ...
done
```